# Adding proper validations on all the parameters coming from the URL in Rest Service

Tags: java, beginner, performance, url, rest

I am working on a `RestService` in which my URL will take lot of parameters. Below are the parameters my URL will take:

- `UserId`: This should always be a `long` and a number in general.
- `DeviceId`: This should always be a `String`.
- `PetaId`: This should always be a `String`.
- `FlowId`: This should be a `long` as well and a number in general.
- `Timeout`: This should be a `long` as well and a number in general.
- `DataFlag`: This should be a `boolean`, true or false.
- `ProcessFlag`: This should be a `boolean`, true or false.

Now I need to do validations on these above properties and if they are not passing correct stuff, then I need to throw proper JSON response with BAD REQUEST error message.

- If anyone is passing `UserId` in the URL, then it should not be empty or `null` and it should be a proper number.
- If anyone is passing `DeviceId` in the URL, then it should not be empty or `null`.
- If anyone is passing `PetaId` in the URL, then it should not be empty or `null`.
- If anyone is passing `FlowId` in the URL, then it should not be empty or `null` and it should be a proper number.
- If anyone is passing `Timeout` in the URL, then it should not be negative or zero.
- If anyone is passing `DataFlag` in the URL, then it should be a `boolean` value.
- If anyone is passing `ProcessFlag` in the URL, then it should be a `boolean` value.

Point is if they are setting any of the above fields, they should set it with proper values otherwise they should not. If any of the above cases fails, then I need to return back a proper JSON error response along with BAD REQUEST 400 message so that they can understand what went wrong.

For example as shown below or if there is anything better, I am open to that as well:

```
{"error": "user id cannot be null or empty"}
```

Now there are two more important things which are mandatory always:

- `FlowId` should always be set. If `FlowId` is not set, like if it is empty or null or zero then I need to return BAD REQUEST and with proper JSON error message like `FlowId` cannot be null or empty or anything better.
- Also at least one of the keys from `UserId`, `DeviceId` and `PetaId` should be valid and set. If all of them are missing/invalid then I need to return BAD REQUEST with proper JSON error message like "all three keys cannot be null or empty" or anything better.

After extracting all the stuff from the URL, I need to pass these values to another library (`DataClient`) which takes these parameter.

- If `UserId` is not empty and not `null` and a valid number, then pass this value to the library.
- If `DeviceId` is not empty and not `null`, then pass this value to the library.
- If `PetaId` is not empty and not `null`, then pass this value to the library.
- If `Timeout` is present in the URL with a valid value, then pass this value, otherwise use the default value of 200.
- If `DataFlag` is present in the URL with a valid `boolean` value, then pass this value, otherwise don't set it if `DataFlag` is not present.
- If `ProcessFlag` is present in the URL with valid a `boolean` value, then pass this value, otherwise don't set it if `ProcessFlag` is not present.

As an example if `UserId` is empty or null and then if we try  to pass this value to the library, then library will throw exception that "UserId cannot be null or empty", so that's why I needed to have all these checks.

Below is my code where I am extracting all the stuff out of it from the URL:

```
@GET
@Path("/json/lime")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getData(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    String client = getClientId();
    if (DataUtils.isEmpty(client)) {
        return Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("{\"error\": \"client id is null or empty\"}").build();
    }

    MultivaluedMap<String, String> m = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    String flowid = null;
    if (m.get("flowid") != null) {
        flowid = m.get(flowid).get(0);
    }
    if (DataUtils.isEmpty(flowid)) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \"flow id cannot be null or empty\"}")
                .build());
    }
    String userId = null;
    if (m.get("userid") != null) {
        userId = m.get("userid").get(0);
        if (DataUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \"user id cannot be null or empty\"}")
                    .build());
        }
    }
    String deviceid = null;
    if (m.get("deviceid") != null) {
        deviceid = m.get("deviceid").get(0);
        if (DataUtils.isEmpty(deviceid)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \"device id cannot be null or empty\"}")
                    .build());
        }
    }
    String petaid = null;
    if (m.get("petaid") != null) {
        petaid = m.get("petaid").get(0);
        if (DataUtils.isEmpty(petaid)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \"peta id cannot be null or empty\"}")
                    .build());
        }
    }

    if (DataUtils.isEmpty(userId) && DataUtils.isEmpty(petaid) && DataUtils.isEmpty(deviceid)) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \"all three keys cannot be null or empty\"}")
                .build());
    }

    long timeout = 200;
    if (m.get("timeout") != null) {
        try {
            timeout = Long.parseLong(m.get("timeout").get(0));
            if (timeout <= 0) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \"invalid timeout is passed\"}")
                        .build());
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \"invalid timeout is passed\"}").build());
        }
    }

    boolean dataFlag = false;
    if (m.get("dataflag") != null) {
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(m.get("dataflag").get(0))) {
            dataFlag = true;
        }
    }

    boolean processFlag = true;
    if (m.get("processflag") != null) {
        if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(m.get("processflag").get(0))) {
            processFlag = false;
        }
    }

    //now build headers
    org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders reqHeader = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();
    reqHeader.add("Context", client);
    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(reqHeader);

    //Now send the request to DataClient
    DataKey key = null;
    Builder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = new DataKey.Builder(Integer.parseInt(flowid));
        if (!DataUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
            builder.setUserId(Long.parseLong(userId));
        }
        if (!DataUtils.isEmpty(deviceid)) {
            builder.setCguid(deviceid);
        }
        if (!DataUtils.isEmpty(petaid)) {
            builder.setUdid(petaid);
        }
        if (dataFlag) {
            builder.dataFlag(dataFlag);
        }
        if (!processFlag) {
            builder.processFlag(processFlag);
        }
        key = builder.addTimeout(timeout).attributeMap(convertToMap(m))
                .addHeaders(entity).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \""+e.getMessage()"\"}")
                .build());
    }

    DataResponse resp = client.getDataHistory(key);

    // if request is unsuccessful
    if (resp.getStatus().ordinal() != 0) {
        int errorCode = resp.getError().getCode();
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(resp.getError().getCode())
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("resp.getResponse()")
                .build());
    }

    // if request was successful
    return Response
            .status(resp.getError().getCode())
            .entity(resp.getResponse()).build();
}
```

Here is the `DataResponse` class which contains actual response and error code and then whether it's a successful response or not.

```
public class DataResponse {
    private final String response;
    private final ErrorCode error;
    private final StatusCode status;

    // constructors/getters     
}
```

The `StatusCode` class contains two properties:

```
public enum StatusCode {
    SUCCESS, ERROR;
}
```

The `ErrorCode` class contains all the status code with proper error messages:

```
public enum ErrorCode {

    OK(200, "NONE", ),
    NO_CONTENT(204, "No Content"),
    BAD_REQUEST(400, "Bad Request")

    // other customized error messages
}
```

I am trying to see whether there is any improvement I can do in my rest service code as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look bad, but it's very repetitive. I see

```
    if (DataUtils.isEmpty(XXX)) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("{\"error\": \"XXX cannot be null or empty\"}")
                .build());
    }
```

a few million times. Except the very first time, where you just

```
    return Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity("{\"error\": \"client id is null or empty\"}").build();
```

instead of throwing. To me it looks like a bug, though I may have missed something in your description.

---

You should have a method like

```
void checkCondition(boolean condition, String errorMessage) {
    if (!condition) {
       throw new WebApplicationException(
           Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
              .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .entity("{\"error\": \"" + errorMessage + "\"}")
              .build());
}
```

and use it like

```
String client = getClientId();
checkCondition(!DataUtils.isEmpty(client), "client id is null or empty");
```

You may want to define more specific constraints like `checkNonEmptyAndNonNull`, but this is possibly past the point of diminishing returns.

---

```
String flowid = null;
if (m.get("flowid") != null) {
    flowid = m.get(flowid).get(0);
}
```

This pattern occurs a lot and I really don't like it. You could write

```
String flowid = m.get("flowid") == null ? null : m.get(flowid).get(0);
```

or better write a helper method like

```
String getFromStupidMap(MultivaluedMap<String, String> m, String key) {
    WhateverStupidType value = m.get(key);
    return value == null ? null : value.get(0);
}
```

and use it like

```
String flowid = getFromStupidMap(m, "flowid");
```

---

What would you do if `m` contained a key multiple times?

---

```
        timeout = Long.parseLong(m.get("timeout").get(0));
```

Consider using Guava's [tryParse](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)).

```
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
```

What if `m.get("timeout").get(0)` returns `null`?

> As an example if UserId is empty or null and then if we try to pass this value to the library, then library will throw exception that "UserId cannot be null or empty", so that's why I needed to have all these checks.

I'm not sure about that. For me, passing

```
whateverurl?userid=&foo=bar
```

should be equivalent to

```
whateverurl?foo=bar
```

When the library doesn't eat it, then you obviously must prepare the data for it, but imposing such a constraint on anyone else IMHO doesn't make much sense.

---

You're also dealing with `null` and empty strings a lot, and I'd suggest to normalize everything by converting `null`s to empty strings ASAP.